# List of lists in SQL

Tags: sql, list

```
CREATE TABLE Persons(
ID int not null,
Name varchar(255) not null, 
Description varchar(255));
```

```
INSERT INTO Persons values(15, "Alex", [["cool",1,19],["strong", 1, 20]]);
```

Is it possible to use a list of lists in this case or should I use another type?

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag appropriately.  "list" is not a standard SQL type.

Comment: Don't do that. Create a properly normalized data model with a one-to-many relationship. If you really want to make your life harder than it needs to be, use a [JSON column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html)

Comment: Could you clarify by showing what rows you expect to be present after your INSERT statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any standard Relational DMBS is not supposed to store such data as it violates  [normalisation principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

While the following schema will suffice to create a table it saves a little time now and creates massive time sink later.

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
  ID int not null,
  Name varchar(255) not null, 
  MultiValueColumnViolates1NF varchar(255)
)
;
```

It violates the 1st NF because column MultiValueColumnViolates1NF allows multiple data tuples in a single cell. Yes, it can hold a list (JSON or XML depends on the RDBMS flavour). Or as normal DBAs call this: Garbage in, garbage out. Or as I call it: Excel tables.

An actual design to store such data preferably is at least in 2NF. Which in this case can be:

```
CREATE TABLE People
(
  Name varchar(255) not null, 
  SingleValueColumn varchar(255)
)
;
```

The INSERT statement will then allow inserting data like:

```
INSERT INTO People 
VALUES
  ( 'Alex', '["cool",1,19]' ),
  ( 'Alex', '["strong", 1, 20]')
;
```

One issue: No unique key possible. So there are multiple rows coming back if data is retrieved for 'Alex'.
Probably not what you want to achieve.

An RDMBS performant way to store this data is in two separate tables.

```
CREATE TABLE People
(
  ID int not null,
  Name varchar(255) not null
)
;

CREATE TABLE People_Data
(
  ID_People    int NOT NULL,
  Key          varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  Value        varchar(200) NOT NULL
)
;
```

The downside to data normalisation is that it makes it more difficult to get the data back (Murphys Law: A database stores data and is unwilling to show it back once it has hold of the data).

If this is just to store data in a database that is *completely used outside the database forever and a day* then go with the first table creation.

If not, please use normalisation to allow fast and efficient analysis of the data through database tools.

Comment: A key-value table is basically EAV and that's not in normalized form. It would be normalized if each attribute had its own named column.

Answer (score 3):

Consider how you will query this data in the future. For example, will you need to search for a person with a specific trait in their description? How would you write that query if it's stored in a "list" as you call it? Using any kind of semi-structured data makes it easy to put data in, but it's not always clear how to search the data afterwards. You should think ahead with this in mind.

If you use the technique of structuring your database into [Normal Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), you will end up with a database that is the most flexible in terms of supporting a wide variety of queries.

Comment: Yeah, JSON-like solutions are extremely fast when querying by PK. But... the moment we need to search by anything else they are a pain in the neck.